# Weaviate Delete Batch Failing with Single ID Mapping Error

Tags: weaviate

When executing a batch delete request with _creationTimeUnix filter, I am getting errors coming back with message `batch delete objects: cannot find objects: finding matching doc ids in shard "xxxxxx": could not get uuid from doc_id=xxxxx`

Delete request looks like:

`curl -XDELETE -H "content-type:application/json" $weaviateUrl/v1/batch/objects -d '"{"match": {"class":"ClassName", "where":{"operator":"LessThanEqual", "path":["_creationTimeUnix"], "valueText":"1705519625249"}},"dryRun":false}'`

It looks like the entire batch fails with even in one ID mapping fails.

Is it possible for the batch code to return back errors and still execute on the successful IDs? What causes the ID mapping to fail? Is there something going wrong at index time or is this strictly a query time issue?

Using weaviate database version 1.23.1

After digging into the source code looks like single ID mapping fails the entire batch in file:
[weaviate source code](https://github.com/weaviate/weaviate/blob/master/adapters/repos/db/shard_write_batch_delete.go#L151)

Answer (score 0):

Duda from Weaviate here.
This is most certainly a bug. Our team will investigate this.

We will open a bug in https://github.com/weaviate/weaviate/issues

Meanwhile, if deleting a single object instead of in batch, does it work as expected?

**Edit:** [the issue is open](https://github.com/weaviate/weaviate/issues/4232)

Thanks!

Comment: Hi! This issue will be fixed in our next release, Weaviatr 1